# I want to attach another network to my basic home network. What options should I consider?

Tags: networking, dhcp, router, usb, gigabit-ethernet

I'm planning to add to my home network by adding a router to the mix. I have a home router connected to the ISP via 5G. I've found that I can't make adjustments to the firewall on this router and I'm overall very limited by the way it's set up. What I plan to do to get around this is to create a new LAN by adding a new router to my room and connecting it to the main router via a gigabit switchport on the router. I want to plug in 3 of my computers into my room router and then go from there. This way, I'll have the regular home network that my family can use and then in my room, I have my own LAN for a homelab and file sharing.

Is there anything I should consider before daisy chaining the two routers? I don't expect it to interfere with my original home network.

Comment: Purchase recommendations are off topic here, though the nested networks is on topic. - I've edited it out, but hardware recommendations would be a good place for that part of the question.

Comment: FWIW, the Hardware Recommendations SE site can be found here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I sort of did this. Essentially my ISP provides an ONR, that's nowhere near as flexible as I'd like

I basically plugged in my 'new' router to the ISP one - connecting a 'lan' socket on the ISP router to the 'wan' socket on my new one. I set a DMZ on the ISP router to the new router so it'd manage port forwards and such, and manage everything from there. The 'DMZ' means that essentially *all* port forwarding and such for the wan is done via the new router.

As such my network looks like this

```
       192.168.1.1                    192.168.1.2
       ISP ROUTER────────────────────►'NEW' Router
            │                         192.168.2.1
            │                         │
            │                         │
            │                         │
            │                         │
            │                         │
            │                         │
            │                         │
            ▼                         ▼
       192.168.1.x general use
                                     192.168.2.x homelab
```

With the DMZ, any ports *explicitly* forwarded on the ISP router are forwarded to the 192.168.1.x subnet, and any other ports on the wan interface can be managed on the new router. It mostly 'just' works